# Calling datarow of stored procedure is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datarow

I want to use the Row of the `Datarow` in my code. What my **datarow** has the value which comes from the stored procedure. See the code below

```
 public void SendMail()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (dr["UserEmail"].ToString() == "10000")
                {
                    string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  "+                         
                    "This is a test mail for reminder. " +

                    string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr.Rows[i]["name"].ToString() + ", <br /><br /> " +        } } }
```

but I am unable to use its Rows.

I tried like this

```
string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr.Rows[i]["UserName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  "+
```

but at `Rows` i am getting error as

> system.data.datarow' does not contain a definition for 'rows'

So how to deal with this.

Also see the datarow screenshot

[image: Datarow]

Comment: 'dr' object contain single row so you can use directly column. like dr["UserName"].ToString()

Comment: It's pretty self explanatory, rows is a property of the datatable not datarow. You are reading the "UserEmail"-field correctly use that for UserName and Name also.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta: but will it assign and read each and every row. ???

Comment: @NK, You can access every row in loop using dr object.

Comment: @KaushikMaheta: So my code is correct for the requirement of looping.. Right ?

Comment: @nk, Yes and DataRow doen't contain 'Rows' property so you can directly access your rows value like dr['columnName'].

Comment: yup got it thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataRow doen't contain 'Rows' property so it give you error.

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (dr["UserEmail"].ToString() == "10000")
            {
                string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr["UserName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  "+                         
                "This is a test mail for reminder. " +

                string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr["name"].ToString() + ", <br /><br /> " +       
            }
         }
```

Comment: hi kaushik, need to ask one more thing here.Can I ?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    if (dr["UserEmail"].ToString() == "10000")
    {
        string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr["UserName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  "+ "This is a test mail for reminder. " + string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr["name"].ToString() + ", <br /><br /> " +  "";      
        } 
    }
}
```

Update:

`dr.Rows` isn't necessary as it gives you error.

Have a read on the following helpful links.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
string StrPriBody = "Dear " + dr["UserName"].ToString() + ", <br /><br />  "+
```